# Define Div text in JavaScript var String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need Define **Div**(**chartContainer1)** value in a JavaScript **"Var"** So that it can be defined in JavaScript Chart Unfortunately am unable to do

HTML:code

```
 <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">

    <div id="chartContainer1">[
    {y: 10, legendText:"Wii U", label: "Wii U 10%"}, 
    {y: 13, legendText:"3DS", label: "3DS 13%"}, 
    {y: 18, legendText:"PS3", label: "PS3 18%"}, 
    {y: 20, legendText:"Xbox One", label: "Xbox One 20%"}
];</div>
```

Chart Code:
I have tried With

```
var dsp = document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML;  
var dps = document.getElementById("chartContainer1").innerText;
```

dataPoints is the place Where i need to define text of Div

```
  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title :{
        text: "Test title"
    },

    data: [{
      type: "stackedBar100",
        dataPoints : dps,
        showInLegend: true, 
        toolTipContent:"{label}"
    }],

  });

  chart.render();
```

Comment: why can't you just define it like normal variable in script?

Comment: CoZ it vl b changing as thy are fetched from database and i have modified with Html in that div

Comment: If i define as normal variable it is working but Cant it b possible to do that

Comment: Can u suggest me on that

Comment: Would it be better to store your data in localstorage or cookies as json, rather than parsing html? then you can use this stored data as the object to chart?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6fvdJ/6/#&togetherjs=l1L6Uudhrg

Comment: Can u Check on that url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use eval to turn it into an object

```
var dps = eval(document.getElementById("chartContainer1").innerText);
```

But be warned about using eval [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: `eval` should be **extremely avoided**. By your approach, shouldn't it better be `JSON.parse(document.getElementById("chartContainer1").innerText);` ?

Comment: @TaoP.R. I agree `eval` should be avoided. The only problem here is that it's not JSON data he/she is trying to get it's a JS object

Comment: Parsed JSON string is a JSON object, isn't it? You can access `dps[0].legendText`, `dps[0].y` after get parsed, so on

Comment: It's not a JSON string, maybe you misunderstood when I say JS object I mean a [JavaScript Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) which although similar is structured different to a [JSON Object](http://www.w3schools.com/json/), notice how with a JS Object the object's properties are not encased in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

***It is not a good practice storing the data inside a DIV that way, because that JSON data will get displayed on the screen before the chart is rendered.***

Please read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Instead, if you really want to attach the data along with a particular HTML element, you should store it in a `data-something` attribute like this:

```
<div id="chartContainer1" data-content='[
    {"y": 10, "legendText":"Wii U", "label": "Wii U 10%"}, 
    {"y": 13, "legendText":"3DS", "label": "3DS 13%"}, 
    {"y": 18, "legendText":"PS3", "label": "PS3 18%"}, 
    {"y": 20, "legendText":"Xbox One", "label": "Xbox One 20%"}
]'></div>
```

And fetch the data from the attribute for render by:

```
var dps = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("chartContainer1").dataset.content);
```

Or classically,

```
var dps = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("chartContainer1").getAttribute("data-content"));
```